# How to share a process?

Tags: c#, winapi, processor

How can I snuggle into another process? Like, share another process's name? So if my application is griddemo.exe, and I want to snug into, let's say, explorer.exe, is that possible? Just read something about CreateRemoteThread() from kernel32. Is that in the right direction? Would there be security/UAC issues?

Comment: You do not have to include tabs in the title.  That is what tags are for.

Comment: You want to have your code execute in another process, unknown to that process?  There's a more common term for that than 'snuggle.'  I believe the term is 'virus.'

Answer (score 3):

First of all sorry, but my answer will be longer as another answers.

I use DLL injection since years in different version of operation system (from windows NT 4.0 till Windows 7) and I had no time any problem with any virus scanner (inclusive both Norton and McAfee in different versions). So I disagree with Stephen Cleary (see his answer) in this aspect.

Usage of `CreateRemoteThread()` is really only one of the ways. **AppInit_DLLs** is another way. Both has its advantage and disadvantage. The main advantage of AppInit_DLLs is a simplicity to inject DLL in any process. The main disadvantages of AppInit_DLLs approach are following:

1. *All GUI application* will load the DLL. If you want to load it only in one process like *explorer.exe* you can't do this. So the working space of all GUI processes will be increased by your DLL. An error in your DLL (especially inside of `DllMain` or in any dependency DLL of your DLL) can crash many processes which you don't currently know.
2. You can not inject your DLL with respect of AppInit_DLLs approach in a console application or in any EXE which have no dependency to User32.dll.
3. You should be very careful inside of your `DllMain`, because it will be called **before** User32.dll will be full initialized. So a safe DLL which you can use inside of `DllMain` of your DLL is Kernel32.dll.

With respect of `CreateRemoteThread()` one can start an additional thread in a process. The main problem of `CreateRemoteThread()` is that its `lpStartAddress` parameter must be **an address from the remote process**. So one have to use functions `OpenProcess`, `VirtualAllocEx` and `WriteProcessMemory` to write some information into the memory of the destination process. To be able to open a process one have to have debug privilege enabled. If you want to do only 2 + 2 inside of the destination process you can copy the corresponding binary code directly into destination process. All real interesting work can be done with usage of some Windows API. So mostly one don't copy a code. Instead of that one call `LoadLibrary("MyPath\\MyDll.dll"`) inside of destination process. Because the prototype of `LoadLibrary` is the same as prototype of `ThreadProc` of `CreateThread` you can call `LoadLibrary` as a `ThreadProc` of `CreateRemoteThread()`. This way has the name **DLL Injection**.

I recommend you to use this DLL Injection **only if it really required**. If your destination application has some other way like plug-ins to load you DLL inside the process your should use this way instead of DLL Injection.

Some general problems you will have to solve after you have a working example of DLL Injection. This problems you can don't see at the first time, but after a long usage of your application you will see its importance:

1. You should find the moment when the destination process are already running before you can use `CreateRemoteThread()`.
2. The destination application must be already initialized before you call `CreateRemoteThread()`. So you should not use `CreateRemoteThread()` too early. In case of explorer.exe you can use a start of your small trigger program from Run registry key. At the moment is explorer.exe fully prepared for DLL injection.
3. You should take in consideration 64-bit version of Windows.
4. Don't forget about DLL relocation inside of destination process. Be careful, that you DLL can be loaded in the destination process at the other address as in your process. Mostly it is a good idea to choose a good base address (linker option) for you DLL which you will inject. The Kernel32.dll can be sometime (very seldom) loaded at the other address as in your source process. You can create a DLL Injection code which are free of this problem.
5. Terminal Services isolates each terminal session by design. Therefore, `CreateRemoteThread` fails if the target process is in a different session than the calling process. The problem you can see on XP (which is not connected to domain) or especially on Vista or Windows 7 if you try make DLL injection from a windows service. To fix the problem you should make DLL Injection either from the process running on the same terminal session as destination process or you have to switch current session before using of `CreateRemoteThread`. Your process must have `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege enabled and use `SetTokenInformation` with `TokenSessionId` parameter. To get session id of the destination process you can use different methods. Functions with the prefix WTS (like `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`) can be very useful.

So everything is not very easy, but it is really interesting subject where you can study a lot of things about operating system. You should only spend a little time to analyse your problem and different ways to solve it before you choose one way which corresponds your project requirements and start programming.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: What do you mean under ASLR? Relocation of your DLL or relocation of Kernel32.dll or some other problem?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: If you mean Address Space Layout Randomization it is absolutely other technique. I mean just usage of /base switch of linker for the DLL which you compile and good code of DLL Injection which work also if destination process has Kernel32.dll loaded on the other place as your source process. Without usage of /base switch your DLL can be relocated during almost loading and will take more memory as needed (will spend the memory).

Answer (score 1):

DLL injection is the traditional method of doing this. It's quite tricky, especially since virus scanners look askance at the practice. So even if you get it working, Norton/McAfee would be likely to block you - or block you in the future.

One easy way of DLL injection is the [AppInit_DLLs registry value](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571). Note that Microsoft has reserved the right to simply remove this functionality (and likely will do so in the future).

The Microsoft-approved way to achieve DLL injection is licensing [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Note that your DLL must be built against the CLR version 4.0 or higher to perform DLL injection safely, because this is the first version to support in-proc side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean injecting your code into another process, then dll injection is one technique:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection

Haven't done this for years, so not sure how happy modern MS Windows operating systems (i.e. post XP) are going to be with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this lately, but another way to do this would be to create a Hook DLL:

1. Create a DLL that contains a Hook Procedure like [MessageProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644987(v=VS.85).aspx).
2. Install this DLL into Windows\System32.
3. Use FindWindows(Ex) to locate your victim process' window.
4. Use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx)() to find the owning thread of that window. This is necessary to avoid injecting your DLL into every single process on the system.
5. Use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) to hook that thread.
6. PostMessage a WM_USER message to the window - activating your Hook DLL if it isn't already active.

This would likely invoke the new [Windows Vista/7 UIPI/UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx) if you're not a sufficiently privileged user but this depends on many factors - your mileage may vary.